# Chrome Packaged apps and Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to understand if Ember.JS would work with chrome packaged apps, as I get these errors when I first run it.

http://pastebin.com/fV8V4fjw

Would these errors end up being a big issue? I can see the localstorage one being an issue, but I can always change that part of the api if needed I suppose.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has anything to do with Ember.js. A quick search of Ember.js shows that it doesn't use any of those variables. You must be using those in your own code.

Comment: The App is empty, there is nothing on it but Ember jQuery and handlebars

Comment: If you remove Ember.js, do those errors go away?

Comment: Ya it does, by removing EmberJS I mean ember and handlebars, I mean I can include ember and handlebars without any issues, but when I create an ember App I get them errors

Comment: I can't say I know what's going on then. One possibility might be that something is iterating over the keys of `window`, causing the errors. As a best guess, I would say you're safe as long as you personally don't access any of those properties.